# Closing automatic popup on button click in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, popup

I'm using the fixed popup, to show the location, according to the latitude and longitude entered by the user.
When you click the button to delete the search, would you like to run or close the automatic popup?
How should I do? I'm using OpenLayers

Fixed popup link: I'm using the fixed popup, to show the location, according to the latitude and longitude entered by the user.

When you click the button to delete the search, would you like to run or close the automatic popup?
How should I do? I'm using OpenLayers

```
var view = map.getView();
var zoom = view.getZoom();
 // Popup overlay

var popup_lat_long = new ol.Overlay.FixedPopup ({
    popupClass: "default", //"tooltips", "warning" "black" "default", "tips", "shadow",
    closeBox: true
});
popup_lat_long.setPixelPosition([10,10], 'auto')
map.addOverlay(popup_lat_long)

document.getElementById('butonSearchLatLong').addEventListener('click', function() {
       
    view = map.getView();
    zoom = view.getZoom();
    
    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value);
    var lon = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lon').value);

    // Converting lat long to mercator projection
    proj_lat_long = ol.proj.fromLonLat([lat, lon])

    // Zoom to lat lon
    map.setView(
        new ol.View({
            center: proj_lat_long,
            zoom: 17
        })
    );

    popup_lat_long.setPixelPosition([10,10], 'auto')
    popup_lat_long.show(proj_lat_long, 'Lat: ' + lat + '<br/> Lon: ' + lon); 
});

document.getElementById('buttonDeleteLatLong').addEventListener('click', function() {
    view.setZoom(zoom);
    map.setView(view)
        
});
```

Fixed popup link: [http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.fixedpopup.html#:~:text=Fixed%20popups%20are%20Openlayers%20popups,its%20position%20on%](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.fixedpopup.html#:%7E:text=Fixed%20popups%20are%20Openlayers%20popups,its%20position%20on%) 20the%20map.&text=Map%20tiles%20by%20Stamen%20Design%2C%20under%20CC%20BY%203.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.Overlay.FixedPopup.html) of the ol-ext fixed popup, you'll see it has `.hide()` method, by which displayed popup can be hidden.

So relevant part of your code could look like this:

```
document.getElementById('buttonDeleteLatLong').addEventListener('click', function() {
  view.setZoom(zoom);
  map.setView(view);
  popup_lat_long.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: How do I mark the answer as accepted?